# Windows batch scripting: Showing date, time and all output in logs

Tags: windows, date, logging, time, batch-file

I have made a script that I am going to call using windows scheduler to back up a Ruby on Rails app I have made.

When I call the command normally in a command window, the output looks like this

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\app>heroku db:pull --confirm app
    Loaded Taps v0.3.23
    Auto-detected local database: postgres://db:pass@127.0.0.1/app?encoding=utf8
    Warning: Data in the database 'postgres://db:pass@127.0.0.1/app?encoding=utf8' will be overwritten and
     will not be recoverable.
    Receiving schema
    Schema:          0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
    Schema:         20% |========                                  | ETA:  00:00:21
    Schema:         40% |================                          | ETA:  00:00:18
    Schema:         60% |=========================                 | ETA:  00:00:12
    Schema:         80% |=================================         | ETA:  00:00:05
    Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:29
    Receiving indexes
    schema_migrat:   0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
    schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:05
    users:           0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
    users:          50% |=====================                     | ETA:  00:00:05
    users:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:10
    Receiving data
    5 tables, 1,000 records
    table1: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
    table2:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
    table3: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
    table4:      100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
    table5:      100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:01
    Resetting sequences
```

Here is my .bat:

```
heroku db:pull --confirm app >> log.txt
```

If I run this twice, this is the output that goes into a file, log.txt

```
Loaded Taps v0.3.23
Auto-detected local database: postgres://db:pass@127.0.0.1/webapp_development?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the database 'postgres://db:pass@127.0.0.1/webapp_development?encoding=utf8' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Receiving schema





Receiving indexes



Receiving data
5 tables, 1,000 records
Resetting sequences

Loaded Taps v0.3.23
Auto-detected local database: postgres://db:pass@127.0.0.1/webapp_development?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the database 'postgres://db:pass@127.0.0.1/webapp_development?encoding=utf8' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Receiving schema





Receiving indexes



Receiving data
5 tables, 1,000 records
Resetting sequences
```

Is there any way to include the exact console output, and also include dates and times of when the script was run? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
Start: 19/10/2012 12:08:04.90 
                                                                               Schema:          0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--Schema:         20% |========                                  | ETA:  00:00:24Schema:         40% |================                          | ETA:  00:00:18Schema:         60% |=========================                 | ETA:  00:00:13Schema:         80% |=================================         | ETA:  00:00:06Schema:        100% |==========================================| ETA:  00:00:00Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:32
                                                                               schema_migrat:   0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| ETA:  00:00:00schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:05
                                                                               users:           0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--users:          50% |=====================                     | ETA:  00:00:05users:         100% |==========================================| ETA:  00:00:00users:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:08
                                                                               schema_migrat:   0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--schema_migrat:   7% |==                                        | ETA:  00:00:06schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
                                                                               users:           0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--users:           3% |=                                         | ETA:  00:00:11users:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
                                                                               projecttechno:   0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--projecttechno:   6% |==                                        | ETA:  00:00:05projecttechno: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
                                                                               technols:        0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--technols:        7% |==                                        | ETA:  00:00:05technols:      100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
                                                                               projects:        0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--projects:        1% |                                          | ETA:  00:00:54projects:      100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
Loaded Taps v0.3.23
Auto-detected local database: postgres://postgres:a@127.0.0.1/webapp_development?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the database 'postgres://postgres:a@127.0.0.1/webapp_development?encoding=utf8' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Receiving schema





Receiving indexes



Receiving data
5 tables, 1,000 records
Resetting sequences
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the date and time is easy using `%date%` and `%time%`.

You could try to redirect stderr (2) to stdout (&1), perhaps that will capture the missing output.

```
echo Start: %date% %time% >>log.txt
heroku db:pull --confirm app >>log.txt 2>&1
echo Stop: %date% %time% >>log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, seems to be a bit of a problem still. see update

Comment: Don't really know how to explain whats going wrong, but I think it's just the formatting of the log file. Can you see any way to fix this?

Comment: @Jamie - It looks like `heroku` modifies the position on the screen as it prints status information to stderr. I don't think it is possible to get a good looking log without a ridiculous amount of work. I would keep the ugly log or else revert back to your original log without the stderr. If absolutely necessary you could redirect stderr to another file and then process and extract required info from it and then append to the regular log, but I wouldn't know what you would need. It could be tricky depending on what you try to extract.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will probably revert back to my old log but include the dates. Thanks for your help.